# Split a single row into multiple ones with explanation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

so I was wondering how would I be abel to split some data values with multiple prices and that sometimes do not have a price into single row

Like this

```
       1   2   3
Mark  30  20  30      
Bella 20  10  11
```

Into

```
Mark 1 30
Mark 2 20
Mark 3 30 
Bella1 20 
Bella 2 10
etc.
```

Comment: You should be able to do this with an SQL power query, an unpivot operation or nested For ... Next loops on an array in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest a multi-stage solution, which is somewhat dirty but working properly.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- **C**opy `H194:J195`.
- Select Cell `H199` then Click **P**aste, **P**aste Special then hit **T**ranspose.
- Next select `H194:J194`, Press **C**trl button then select `H196:J196` & then **C**opy.
- Select Cell `H202` then Click **P**aste, **P**aste Special & **T**ranspose.

**For Helper Value:**

- Enter **N**ame in `K199:K200` & **N**umber `L199:L200` (*these values determine how many times, repeat Name in `G199:G204`*).
- Enter `1` in Cell `J199`.
- Formula in Cell `J200`: `=J199+L199`, fill it down.
- To get **Sr. No.** in `F199:F204`, enter `1` in `F199` , `2` in `F200` then select both and Copy down.

**For Name:**

- Formula in cell `G199` & fill it down.

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F199,$J$199:$K$202,2),"")`

**N.B.**

- For neatness, later on you may hide HELPER VALUES.

[image]

- You may adjust cell references for Transpose & Formula as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Power Query unpivot the table:

1. Select the Range and go to Data- From Table/Range- check "My table has headers":
   [image]
2. Select Column 1, 2, 3 and go to Transform- select Unpivot Columns- go to Home- Close and load:
   [image]

Comment: This solved it, hahaha I have now taken a course in this and am profficient in it.